# Unpivot/flatten from a comma delimited column

Tags: sql, unpivot, sql-server-2019

I have a SQL table with two columns

| Location | Sites |
| --- | --- |
| L1 | Sa,Sb,Sc,Sd |
| L2 | Sa,Sb,Sx |

I would like a query to flatten this to

| Location | Site |
| --- | --- |
| L1 | Sa |
| L1 | Sb |
| L1 | Sc |
| L1 | Sd |
| L2 | Sa |
| L2 | Sb |
| L2 | Sx |

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I hope you now have learnt to avoid storing data as comma separated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Location
      ,[value] AS Site
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Sites, ',')
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to change compatibility level for the db, but that worked a charm.